# Insert data into chrome storage

Tags: javascript

I want to store favourite and deleted ids in my database. I wrote 2 functions:

```
function INSERT_BLOCKED(id) {
    chrome.storage.local.get("blocked", function (data) {
        if (data.blocked == null)
            data.blocked = [];


        if (!data.blocked.includes(id)) {
            data.deleted.push(id);
            chrome.storage.local.set(data);
        }

    });
}

function INSERT_FAVOURITE(id) {
    chrome.storage.local.get("favourite", function (data) {
        if (data.favourite == null)
            data.favourite = [];


        if (!data.favourite.includes(id)) {
            data.deleted.push(id);
            chrome.storage.local.set(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Is there any way to combine theese functions? I can't really pass `data.blocked` to functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the parameter and leverage the nature of JavaScript for this;

```js
function insert_storage(container, id) {
  chrome.storage.local.get(container, function(data) {
    // you can access an items members using the [ ] syntax
    if (data[container] == null)
      data[container] = [];


    if (!data[container].includes(id)) {
      data.deleted.push(id);
      chrome.storage.local.set(data);
    }

  });
}
```